# C/Glib Strings that should be freed by the caller

Tags: c, glib

I am using glib, 
it has a lot of functions that return strings that should be freed myself.
Can I, pass these functions to other functions?

**Example:** *function1* returns a string that must be freed for the caller.
*function2* returns a pointer to a string that must be freed also.

```
gchar *string = function2(function1("something"));
g_free (string);
```

How should I free the string returned from function1? Is this necessary?

Thanks a lot, 
and sorry for my english

Comment: We can see in the main page and the question page whether a question has been answered or closed, you do not need to change the title of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is necessary to free the string returned by `function1`. To allow you to do this, you need to take a copy of the return value :-

```
gchar* temp = function1("something");
gchar* string = function2(temp);
g_free(temp);
g_free(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the example you give:

```
gchar *string = function2(function1("something"));
g_free (string);
```

You *can't* free the string from `function1()`. This is a memory leak. So while I know it's nice to compress things, you should slow down:

```
gchar *temp, *string;
temp = function1("something");
string = function2(temp);
g_free(temp);
temp = NULL;
g_free(string);
```

Otherwise, every time that code runs, `function1()` will be allocating more memory that never gets freed, and if your application runs for a long time, your program will start slowly running out of avaliable memory (because of all that allocated memory that is never `free()`d).

Another alternative is to write a wrapper around `function2()`:

```
gchar *function2_wrapper(gchar *c)
{
    gchar *ret = function2(c);
    free(c);
    return ret;
}

gchar *string = function2_wrapper(function1("something"));
```

But in my opinion that's probably more effort than it's worth, and anyone looking at your code may be lost, think there is a memory leak when there isn't, and rewrite it and get hit with a double-`free()` error at runtime and have no idea what's going on,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true, as @DaveRigby and others are [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296605/640650) out, that you need to get the pointer value returned from `function1()` to free it.  But there is big **if**!

If you are referring glib functions like `g_string_append()` as `function1()`, you should *not* free it. Because those functions return what you passed on.

Let's say you have

```
GString *s = g_string_new("foo");
```

and you want to have `"http://foo/bar"`, you can do:

```
s = g_string_prepend(g_string_append(s, "/bar"), "http://");
use_my_string(s);
g_string_free(s);
```

I know the above example is not the best one but hope you can see the point.  GString functions can be said *destructive*. It does not create a copy of given strings.